# Missing Contacts from Contacts Framework (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, contacts-framework

For some reason, a few of my contacts are missing from my tableView. I believe am I fetching all the necessary keys and have reviewed Apple's documentation, but am still stuck. Below is my code:

```
  -(void)fetchContactsandAuthorization {
// Request authorization to Contacts
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES)
    {

        //keys with fetching properties
        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *phone;
            NSString *fullName;
            NSString *firstName;
            NSString *lastName;
            UIImage *profileImage;
            NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                firstName = contact.givenName;
                lastName = contact.familyName;
                if (lastName == nil) {
                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                }else if (firstName == nil){
                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                }
                else{
                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                }

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                if (image != nil) {
                    profileImage = image;
                }else{
                    profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                }

                NSString *number = contact.phoneNumbers.firstObject.value.stringValue;

                if (number == (NSString *)NSNull.null || number == nil) {
                    [contactNumbersArray addObject:@"NO NUMBER"];
                } else {
                    [contactNumbersArray addObject:number];
                }


                arrayPhoneData = contactNumbersArray;
                NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
                [arrayTableData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"]]];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[tableViewContactData reloadData];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }
      }
  }];
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!!!!

Comment: post a missing and a non-missing contact, including contained group, to compare

Answer (score 0):

```
`
let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any]

        do {
            let contactStore = AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().contactStore
            try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])) { (contact, pointer) -> Void in
                if !contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {
                    contacts.append(contact)
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {

            print(error.description, separator: "", terminator: "\n")
        }


        let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()

        contactPickerViewController.delegate = self

        present(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
`
```

stick this in your app delegate

```
var contactStore = CNContactStore()

   class func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
```

Try double checking your predicate. I have had trouble with the predicate restricting the contacts I have been searching for and removed it entirely in the past. Not also that but you could try adding more keys to your contact keys. You're potentially restricting your search with keysToFetch.

Comment: Tried to add more keys, but that didn't seem to work. How did you get cnContacts to  work if you removed the predicate?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

You should access the Contact Book differently.

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (granted == NO) {
            //show access denied popup
            return ;
        }


        NSError* contactError;
        CNContactStore* addressBook = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];
        [addressBook containersMatchingPredicate:[CNContainer predicateForContainersWithIdentifiers: @[addressBook.defaultContainerIdentifier]] error:&contactError];
        NSArray *keysToFetch = @[CNContactMiddleNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
        CNContactFetchRequest * request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc]initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];


        [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&contactError usingBlock:^(CNContact * __nonnull contact, BOOL * __nonnull stop){\

            NSString *firstName = contact.givenName;
            NSString *lastName = contact.familyName;

           //recommend to use a function like this one: [self parseContactWithContact:contact];
        }];


    }];
});
```